# Using Imwrite command in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-guide

```
[fname1 path] = uigetfile('*.*','open image file');%*.*
[path,name,ext,ver] = fileparts(fname1);
handles.fname = strcat(name,ext);
a = imread(handles.fname);
r = imresize(a,[256,256]);
file = 'C:\Main CBIR\query images\r.bmp';
[fname,map] = rgb2ind(r,32);
imwrite(fname,map,file);
```

Above code saves image(BMP) with name `r` in specified path/folder. But how to save image with its own name? I mean if i input image with name `rose.jpg` how to save `rose.bmp`  using above code? instead above code saves image with `r.bmp`. How can i go for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the file name (e.g., `'rose'`) stored in variable `name` returned from `fileparts`. you can use it to create the new file name:

```
file = fullfile( 'c:', 'Main CBIR', 'query images', [name, '.bmp'] );
```

Comment: Thank you, however if i use `imread` after `imwrite(fname,map,file);` command in above code I"m getting an error. `imwrite(fname,map,file);
b = imread(fname);` i got an error like `??? Error using ==> strfind`
`Input strings must have one row.`

`Error in ==> imread at 329`
`if (strfind(filename, '://'))`

`Error in ==> CBIR_MJP>insert_Callback at 97`
`b = imread(fname);`
Y this error?

Comment: you need to get your code straight. `name` is a string so is `file`. However, `fname` is **NOT** a string and cannot be used as an input to `imread`. Try `imread( file );`

Comment: `imread(file)` also results in error. `??? Error using ==> ``fileparts at 17`
`Input must be a row vector of characters.`

`Error in ==> Pre_processing>Pre_processing_OpeningFcn at 60`
`[path,name,ext,ver] = fileparts(fname);`

`Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 221`
    `feval(gui_State.gui_OpeningFcn, gui_hFigure, [], ``guidata(gui_hFigure), varargin{:});`
*file* just contains *bmp* image i think, after this command I'm converting to *index* as you can see in my code just above `imwrite`. But i want to read that image which is get saved in specified folder.